# Masking CALayer with Lines

Tags: ios, calayer, mask, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to find an efficient way to perform the following clipping operation on a `CAShapeLayer` that I have.

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I have a `CAShapeLayer` whose circular path consists of a `UIBezierPath` that has been constructed using the method `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:]` (this is a full circle from 0 to 2PI radians), and inside of that circle, I want to cut out multiple lines that are drawn at different angles, making the area below the cut out lines transparent on the circle. I want these lines to begin and end at points on the outside of the circle aka the edges of the CAShapeLayer's path.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to use the `mask` property on the `CAShapeLayer` to accomplish this, or whether I should abandon the idea of cutting out from the full circle and just draw each arced triangle separately as different `CAShapeLayers`.

Thank you for your any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by forgetting about using masks. Instead, I just constructed a `UIBezierPath` using the `moveToPoint:` and `addLineToPoint:` methods in order to draw the desired portions of the circle.